# Sonata Error Pages

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm struggling with error pages.

According the documentation I understand that as soon as i've catch_exceptions in my config it will take _page_internal_error_not_found and _page_internal_error_fatal as my error pages (after core-routes-update and create-snapshots). To me this is not the case. It will take the same old one for 404 as we can see in the demo: http://demo.sonata-project.org/somesitethatdoesntexist .

Does someone know how to override the error pages?

Kind regards,
Marc

Comment: The issue is also present on sonata project demo page: http://demo.sonata-project.org/a404

Comment: I've posted an issue in github: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/issues/195